# Unable to update database via TableAdapter

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, tableadapter

I'm having a problem when trying to insert, delete or update data in the SQL Server database with VB.NET.

I'm trying to insert data in two different ways, but Neither of them works:

- inserting directly throught tableadapter with the "Insert" command.
- with the manipulation of an object "table" which is used to update the table adapter in sequence.

```
Dim acmd As New DSGTableAdapters.t001_comandosTableAdapter
Dim tcmd As New DSG.t001_comandosDataTable

acmd.Insert(1, 1, "Teste dado", "Teste ação")

tcmd = acmd.GetData
tcmd.Addt001_comandosRow(2, 2, "teste dado2 através de tabela", "teste ação2")

acmd.Update(tcmd)
```

I'm able to manipulate data directly trhought Visual Studio's Database Explorer, but In code I'm not achieving the same.

- Visual Studio 2010 (VB)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 v. 10.00.2531
- Provider: .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server
- Database is in local machine, with access granted.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Are you receiving errors or is the data just not showing up in the database? If you are receiving errors, you need to add them to your question so we can help your resolve your issue. If you are not receiving errors, have you stepped through the code in debugger to see if every line is being executed?

Comment: It's hard to say. We don't know how your INSERT SQL-command looks like, nor what these DSGTableAdapters.t001_comandosTableAdapter really are. If you'd use a SqlCommand then you would do something like: var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ..."); cmd.ExecuteNonquery();

Comment: Yes, I've been executing the code without errors and doing it by step-by-step. I'll try the ExecuteNonQuery method.